# use ORA_ROWSCN value for update a column in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am tryng to complete a new column in a table.

I need that the value of this new column be the creation date of the row.
My best efford for the previous values of the table is use the ORA_ROWSCN.

I achieve select this value in a query but the update fails:

```
UPDATE mytable AA 
  SET AA.reg_date = SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(AA .ORA_ROWSCN);
```

other option that fails too:

```
UPDATE mytable AA 
  SET AA.reg_date = SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP
  (
  SELECT bb.ORA_ROWSCN   
  FROM mytable bb
  WHERE bb.ID= AA.ID
  );
```

Any option? thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and include information on the errors your queries are generating. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only reliable way of retrieving the creation date would have been by making sure you persisted that information when you created the rows.

Using `scn_to_timestamp` with `ora_rowscn` to retrieve the creation timestamp can't work for the following reasons:

- If it works, it will only give you an approximate timestamp based on the `SCN`. Not an exact time.
- The `ora_rowscn` changes when the row is updated. So in some instances, you would be getting the update timestamp, not the creation timestamp.
- The `ora_rowscn` is known to change when other data in the same data block is updated as well. So the value may be completely wrong and unrelated to your row.
- And, to make matters worse, if the `scn` is too old, the `scn_to_timestamp` simply won't work. This is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions175.htm#SQLRF06325).

> The association between an SCN and a timestamp when the SCN is generated is remembered by the database ***for a limited period of time***.

Answer (score 1):

ORA_ROWSCN is by default the last update of the whole block, so all rows within the block will have the same (the one assigned during last DML). The table would need to have created with ROWDEPENDENCIES to store the SCN for each row (requires additional space).

Also SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP function is limited in range what SCNs it can translate to timestamps. This mapping is stored only for certain amount of time, it's most like the error you experience.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `ORA_ROWSCN` at all?

You can simply create a column of a native `timestamp` type with a default value which will be automatically applied for a new row (if you don't override it).

```
alter table <table name> add column <column name> timestamp default systimestamp;
```

This solution is much closer to your goal.

Comment: the problem is the legacy rows, the rows that exists before to create this column

Comment: well you can convert your previous timestamp to the normal one... I don't see a big problem here.